# ActionBar Compatibility issue with API 15

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I have an issue with actionBar compatibility on API level 15 for Android. The up button doesn't work well with this API level

I use the sample project called "actionbarcompat" provided in the android-sdk folder, so I have imported all class's and I extends all my activities with ActionBarActivity. I also add this piece of code in the Manifest for all my activities :

```
<activity
    android:name="fr.appsolute.rescue.MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_info"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

and in my ActionBarActivity :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This permit the user to touch the up button (with the app icon) to return to the MainActivity

This code works well with Android 2.3.3 and 4.2, but doesn't work with 4.0.1 and I don't understand why. When the user touch the up button, nothing happens.

Thanks for your help.

PS : I can't use an external library, I have to use native code

Comment: That sample is deprecated. Use ActionbarSherlock.

Comment: Thanks @rciovati, ActionbarSherlock works very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using ActionBarSherlock

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it isn't working. I agree it is strange that it only fails on API 15.

An alternative to calling `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)` could be calling `finish()`. This would close your current activity and go to the previous activity in the stack. It may give you the same desired result.